# Why Heroku is always unable to verify my credit and debit cards?

Tags: heroku, credit-card, card

I've tried 4-5 debits cards and 2 credit cards of different banks but the error "Unable to verify your card. Please try later or contact your financial institution for help." always comes up. I'm sure the information I'm filling is correct and international transactions are also activated. How do I find out what is the problem?

Comment: Please just contact them. I had the same problem with all my cards but the problem was resolved immediately after I contacted them. Create the ticket here: https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new?id=2

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about your card issuer country.
In case it India this might help others.

> Effective October 1, 2021, new Reserve Bank of India (RBI) regulations state that no automatic recurring payments may be processed using India-issued credit cards without an additional factor of authentication (AFA).

> Because of these new regulations, Heroku is currently unable to verify and process payments with India-issued credit cards for Heroku Online customers. Enterprise India-based customers are not impacted.

More you can find on [heroku](https://help.heroku.com/04UOS4A3/why-am-i-seeing-the-error-unable-to-verify-your-card-when-trying-to-add-or-update-a-credit-card) itself.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you're entering the correct address details you gave to your bank. Once happened to me and thats how I fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I checked the address, its same as that given to bank, still not working.

Comment: Re-check everything else, try removing cookies thats all I can say

Answer (score 2):

Also if you are from Nigeria note that CBN asked banks to decline any foreign transaction as from June 2022 till further.

Comment: C'mon I'm having a big issue now, is there any way around it mate??

Comment: Yeah, You can use Chipper Cash or Geegpay they both provide international Dollar Cards that your can fund with Nigerian Naira (NGN) and use everywhere.

Comment: Given that this answer is a non-technical response (no code provided), it will likely get flagged for deletion. To avoid this (create a more resilient answer), provide a link + source for the information provided above.

Comment: The technical fix to this is to ensure the Postal code is correct and the city, state, and country should be in Capital Case. Try and confirm the fix. It worked for me